# Is it necessary to force a newly registered user to login?

Tags: security, authentication, websecurity

In a web application, is there a security advantage to forcing a newly registered user to manually log into their account, or is it safe to automatically log in a new registration? Assume that the user is registering using a local registration/login strategy, and their credentials are an email address and password they specified at the time of registration.

Comment: This question might be better asked on [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks John, I'll ask it there.